# Getting the pixel value from the user defined Image (which converted form a FeatureCollection)

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, raster-conversion, pixel

There is a simple FeatureCollection, and the `reduceToImage()` function can convert this FC to a google-earth-engine image. How can I get the pixel value from this image.

This is the JS code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/88c44fdcb146bdbf5d744172b92a81e1

```
var F1 = ee.Feature(null,{value:1});
var F2 = ee.Feature(null,{value:2});
var F3 = ee.Feature(null,{value:3});
var F4 = ee.Feature(null,{value:4});

var FC = ee.FeatureCollection([F1,F2,F3,F4])
    
var img = FC.reduceToImage({
  properties: ['value'],
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
});    

var imgadd10 = img.add(ee.Image.constant(10))
```

From the code above, theoretically, we can find that the pixcel value of "imgadd10" is [11,12,13,14], but how? I test the `Image.toDictionary()` and `Image.reduce()`, it doesn't work.

This is the source of inspiration for the code above, it realized the pixel-by-pixel processing through the mutual conversion between vector and raster.
[enter link description here](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/376172609)

Comment: The sample code you gave does not return an image since `reduceToImage()` only returns an image for pixels where the feature geometry intersects. Additionally, a reducer is applied, so instead of writing all individual values in the Feature Collection it will only write the mean of them (2.5). What do you try to accomplish with the code?

Comment: This is a bad idea and you should not do it.  You will never be able to get this to scale this way (instead of being able to process ~thousands of images, you will be limited to just thousands of pixels). That said, it seems like there is nothing in your forward model definition that couldn't be applied to entire images; it's just math.  What about your model makes you think you need to isolate individual pixels to operate on them.